# Conditional entropy and independent conditioning variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Let $X,Y,Z,Y',Z'$ be random variables where $Y\sim Y', Z\sim Z'$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, while $Y'$ and $Z'$ are, in the sense that we have

- $p(X,Y,Z)=p(X|Y,Z)p(Y)p(Z)$
- $p(X,Y',Z')=p(X|Y',Z')p(Y',Z')$
- $p(X|Y,Z)=p(X|Y',Z')$

Is $H(X|Y,Z)=H(X|Y',Z')$?

It seems whether $p(Y,Z)$ factorises or not does not affect the value of $H(X|Y,Z)$ but somehow the rigorous argument is missing.

Comment: The first paragraph looks contradictory. What does $(Y,Z) \sim (Y',Z')$ mean? Perhaps you mean that the marginals are equal? Then you should write $Y\sim Y'$  and $Z \sim Z'$

Comment: @leonbloy: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not clear, because you don't specify how $Z$ is (jointly) related with the other variables. Assuming you mean that the conditional are the same ($P(X|Y,Z)=P(X|Y',Z')$) :
$$H(X|Y,Z)=-\sum_{y,z} p(y,z) \sum_{x} p(x|y,z)\log p(x|y,z)  $$
This implies that for both scenarios the inner sum (the entropies conditioned on particular values: $H(X|Y=y,Z=z)$) are the same. Hence, in general the conditined entropy will not depend solely on the marginals. That is, $H(X|Y,Z) \ne H(X|Y',Z') $

Comment: I'm sorry for my question being unclear; tried to clarify.

So for the scenario I've presented above the conditional entropies are equal, because the conditionals are the same? The fact whether $p(Y,Z)$ factorises or not doesn't affect the conditional entropy?

Comment: As I tried to explain, in your case $H(X|Y=y,Z=z)$ are the same but $H(X|Y,Z)$ are not.

Comment: And this is because $p(y',z')\neq p(y,z)=p(y)p(z)=p(y')p(z')$, right? Can one only say $\neq$ or is there a way to show that $H(X|Y,Z)\leq H(X|Y',Z')$ the intuition being that conditioning on two independent variables can even reduce more entropy in $X$?